# AWS Shared EC2 sharing details

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems

I am launching an EC2 instance with Shared tenancy. Can I get to know what are the other processes run on the same host by other users?

If the size of my `/tmp` reports 100% usage whereas the current contents of the disk under my login is only 50%, does that mean the disk usage (`df`) is taking size details from other users' file size as well, present under the same folder?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Amazon EC2 instance is a virtual machine. It has **zero visibility** of anything else running on the same host computer.

- Individual 'virtual CPUs' are not shared
- Memory is not shared
- Network is logically separated
- Disk is virtual, but logically separated
- The disk is viewable only from that specific EC2 instance

**Bottom line:** Nothing that anybody else does on the same host will *not* impact your virtual machine. Whatever you are experiencing with `df` is purely related to your own instance and is related to the operating system you are using (Linux). It is unrelated to AWS/EC2.

Comment: Thanks a ton for reconfirming my understanding. Where I got confused, the size of the sub-folders and the parent folder didn't match up. How is that possible?

Comment: Don't know. That's a Linux question. Feel free to create a Question on ServerFault with the details and somebody will likely answer.